# List view filter criteria via Apex or Query or API

Tags: apex, list-view

Is there any way we can get ListView Filter criteria using API or APEX or SOQL.

Answer (score 7):

You can sort of do this via API and apex code, depending on what exactly you're looking for.

```
private static String filterCriteria(String authToken, String objType, String listView){
  system.debug('ObjType: '+objType+'-- listView: '+listView);

    Id listViewId = [SELECT id FROM ListView WHERE developerName = :listView AND sObjectType=:objType].id;
    String ep = URL.getSalesforceBaseUrl().toExternalForm() + '/services/data/v43.0/sobjects/'+objType+'/listviews/'+listViewId+'/describe';
    HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest();
    req.setMethod('GET');
    req.setHeader('Authorization','Bearer '+authToken);
    req.setEndpoint(ep);
    HttpResponse res = new Http().send(req);
    system.debug('Res body: '+res.getBody());
    queryWrapper qw = (queryWrapper)json.deserialize(res.getBody(), queryWrapper.class);

    return (qw.query.containsIgnoreCase('WHERE')?qw.query.substringAfter('WHERE'):'No filter criteria for this list view';

}

private class queryWrapper{
    String query{get;set;}

}
```

objType and listView are the API name of the object and the list view, respectively.  Example output:

> WHERE Id IN (SELECT ContactId FROM CampaignMember WHERE CampaignId = '70134000001NYuE') ORDER BY Name ASC NULLS FIRST, Id ASC NULLS FIRST

I had to use oauth to get a token because this is used in a lightning component, but if you're not using it from a custom component you can skip fetching the access token and replace:

> req.setHeader('Authorization','Bearer '+authToken);

With:

> req.setHeader('Authorization','Bearer '+Userinfo.getSessionId());

If filter scope is important to you, you'll want to adjust the .containsIgnoreCase and .substringAfter values to account for that.  Since not all listview queries have 'USING SCOPE', I think you'd want something like:

> (qw.query.containsIgnoreCase('USING SCOPE')?qw.query.substringAfter('USING SCOPE'):(qw.query.containsIgnoreCase('WHERE')?qw.query.substringAfter('WHERE'):'No filter criteria for this list view';

Also, your endpoint will clearly be different if you have not activated my domain.

Answer (score 5):

You can access the [ListViewFilter](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_meta.meta/api_meta/meta_listview.htm#listViewFilter) via the Metadata API [ListView](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_meta.meta/api_meta/meta_listview.htm). Unfortunately ListView isn't currently one of the [Supported Metadata Types](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_metadata_supported_types.htm) in the Apex Metadata API.

The [Apex Wrapper Salesforce Metadata API](https://github.com/financialforcedev/apex-mdapi) would be a good starting point as it has ListViewFilter.

Otherwise, consider voting for [Provide programmatic access to ListView Filters](https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000a0xNAAQ) and raising the use case in the [Apex Metadata API](https://success.salesforce.com/_ui/core/chatter/groups/GroupProfilePage?g=0F930000000PbSh) group.